# Google Adsense 1099-Misc

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1099, google

Just received my ***Google Adsense 1099-Misc*** in the mail and I'm a little confused as to what approach I need to take in the order of paying my taxes.

Last year my income was almost exactly the same as it was this year however this year the field which states '***Fed Income Tax Withheld***' has a **$$** value in it appose to last year when it didn't have any values in that field, however my revenue total was still filed under **Nonemployee Compensation**.

Does this mean google took money out for me? Is this them showing me how much I owe? I'm extremely confused..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean google took money out for me? Is this them showing me how much I owe?

Federal income tax withheld means that the payer already deducted some of your earnings from your paycheck to pay federal income tax. This is tax that you have already paid and you may get some of it back with your tax return.

> last year it didn't have any values in that field

Something in your situation may have changed since last year. [Google AdSense](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1322037?hl=en) says they may withhold taxes if:

- if you are subject to back-up withholding as described on Form W-9
- if you do not fill in Section 10 on Form W-8BEN with a treaty number and 0%, and do not provide a United States TIN in Part 1 Box 6
- if you do not claim complete exemption in Section 12 of Form 8233
- if the tax information entered on your tax form is found to be incorrect or inaccurate

Comment: So some of my taxes are paid, I just have to pay the rest? What they paid I may get revenue back?

Comment: @Land when you fill out our tax return, the money that Google withheld will be counted against your tax liability. If you still owe money, you will pay the IRS. If the sum of  withholding plus all other withholding and any estimated taxes you may have paid is greater than your tax liability you will get a refund.

Comment: @Land, Eric Johnson is correct. You'll need to fill out a tax return to know whether you end up owing money or you're owed money. This can be a pain by hand, so try using some software like the IRS's free file or turbotax.